# htaccess to treat a single file differently from all others

Tags: .htaccess

I have my htaccess configured to rewrite all filenames

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^contst/(.*)$ /contst/index.html?doc=$1 [L,NC]
```

How do I exclude a specific file (contst/blahblah.php) from being picked up by this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^contst/blahblah\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^contst/(.*)$ /contst/index.html?doc=$1 [L,NC]
```

or

```
RewriteCond $1 !^blahblah\.php$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^contst/(.*)$ /contst/index.html?doc=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: sorry i missed the response when it was originally posted